# Submitting a multi-tab page when the last tab is reached

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, formwizard

I have a multi-tab form that contains 6 tabs.I wanted to insert it in the database but i dont know how to. I want it to submit when the user fill up the last tab. And I also wanted to change the button from NEXT to Submit button when the last tab is active. Also I want the user to be able to review his answers and go between from tab to tab. 
Below is the jquery that validates the input fields and adjusts the progress bar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $validator = $("#wizardForm").validate({
    rules: {

      emp_fname: {
        required: true
      },
      emp_lname: {
        required: true
      },

      gender: {
        required: true
      },

      CivilStatus: {
        required: true
      },

      citizenship: {
        required: true
      },

    }
  });

  $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    'tabClass': 'nav nav-tabs',
    onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
      var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
      var $current = index + 1;
      var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
      $('#rootwizard').find('.progress-bar').css({
        width: $percent + '%'
      });
    },

    'onNext': function(tab, navigation, index) {
      var $valid = $("#wizardForm").valid();
      if (!$valid) {
        $validator.focusInvalid();
        return false;
      }
    },
    'onTabClick': function(tab, navigation, index) {
      var $valid = $("#wizardForm").valid();
      if (!$valid) {
        $validator.focusInvalid();
        return false;
      }
    },
  });
});



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<form id="wizardForm" method="POST">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="tab1">
      <div class="row m-b-lg">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="exampleInputName">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_fname" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group  col-md-3">
              <label for="MiddleName">Middle Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" name="emp_mname" id="MiddleName" placeholder="Middle Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group  col-md-3">
              <label for="exampleInputName2">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" name="emp_lname" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group  col-md-3">
              <label for="exampleInputName2">Name Extension</label>
              <select id="extension" class="form-control col-md-2 col-xs-12" name="nameExt">
                <option selected disabled="">---</option>
                <option value="Jr.">Jr.</option>
                <option value="Sr.">Sr.</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

These are the buttons that enables the user to go on the next tab.

```html
<ul class="pager wizard">
  <li class="previous"><a href="Add_Emp.php#" class="btn btn-default" name="Previous" id="prev">Previous</a>
  </li>
  <li class="next"><a href="Add_Emp.php#" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Next" id="next">Next</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just place the submit button for the form on the last tab?

Your next and previous buttons could be placed as needed within each tab pane.

You are missing some of the form code above, so it doesn't show the buttons you refer to.

Comment: the buttons are dynamic. How should i do that using jquery or any simple script?

Comment: Are the buttons outside the tab section? If so, you can keep track of the current tab, and change the labels and/or if each is enabled depending upon the current tab. IOW, when you change tabs, you set the enabled/disabled state on them. When on tab 1, the prev is disabled. @Laurie: When on the last tab, change the label of the next button to "Save" or "Submit" or whatever you need it to be. Or better yet, when you are on the last tab, hide the next button, and make a save button (type='submit') visible.

Comment: I noticed that the buttons refer to a php file. I would remove that entirely and just use jQuery to bind to the click event, except for the "Save" button where you actually want to submit to the server.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm new to jquery, how should I do it and where shall I place it in the jquery code above?

Answer (score 0):

Change the buttons like this:

```html
<ul class="pager wizard">
  <li class="previous"><div class="btn btn-default" name="Previous" id="prev">Previous</div>
  </li>
  <li class="next"><div href="Add_Emp.php#" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Next" id="next">Next</div>
  </li>
  <li class="next"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default hidden" value="Save" id="btn_save">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Add to your css:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Change the Javascript you have above to:

```
  $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    'tabClass': 'nav nav-tabs',
    onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
      var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
      var $current = index + 1;
      var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
      $('#rootwizard').find('.progress-bar').css({
        width: $percent + '%'
      });
      set_buttons(index);   //  Set the button enabled and visibility
    },

    'onNext': function(tab, navigation, index) {
      var $valid = $("#wizardForm").valid();
      if (!$valid) {
        $validator.focusInvalid();
        return false;
      }
    },
    'onTabClick': function(tab, navigation, index) {
      var $valid = $("#wizardForm").valid();
      if (!$valid) {
        $validator.focusInvalid();
        return false;
      }
    },
  });
});

//  This function sets the buttons enable and visibility based on which tab is active.
function set_buttons(index) {
    if(index == 0) {
        // On first tab, so disable the previous button
        $('#prev').prop('disabled',true);
        $('#next').removeClass('hidden');       //  Make sure next is visible
        $('#btn_save').addClass('hidden');      //  Make sure save button is hidden.
    } else if(index == navigation.find('li').length) {
        // On last tab, so hide the next button, make the save button visible
        $('#prev').prop('disabled',false);      //  Make sure prev is enabled.
        $('#next').addClass('hidden');          //  Make sure next is hidden
        $('#btn_save').removeClass('hidden');   //  Make sure save button is visible.
    } else {
        //  On a middle tab (not first or last), enable previous and next buttons, hide save button
        $('#prev').prop('disabled',false);      //  Make sure prev is enabled.
        $('#next').removeClass('hidden');       //  Make sure next is visible
        $('#btn_save').addClass('hidden');      //  Make sure save button is hidden.
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code above so there may be some errors, but it should be pretty close. Use your browser's debugger (Chrome or FireFox) to look for errors. I had to make a couple of assumptions to test for the last tab number and that the var index is an index of the tabs.

To test, I would have to have all of the code on the page, but you should be able to figure it out by the comments and using a debugger.